# Can a workflow on one list update fields in a linked (joined) list?

Tags: 2010, list, workflow

I have two lists in Sharepoint 2010 that have a 1:1 relationship. When a user creates an entry in the first list (call it "Requests"), this triggers a workflow that creates a corresponding entry in a "Reviews" list. The Reviews list as a "ReqID" column, so each Review has a pointer to the Request item it relates to.

The first part is working ok. Each time a Request is added, a workflow creates a Review and sets some fields in the Review appropriately.

Now, what I need to do is have a workflow on the second list such that-

- When the Review is updated and the Review status is "Closed"
- Copies the value of the "Review Outome" field from the Review to equivalent field in the Request identified by the "ReqID" field.

Is there a way to do this? Once the second list item is created it seems to be cut adrift. Even though I have an ID to join the two lists, there don't seem to be any "update List item by Listname.ItemID" actions available.

Note I don't have code access to the server, I think workflow actions are my only option.

Comment: Thank you Arsalan! I was being a bit dim, looking through the Sharepoint UI looking for a function that gave this option to update a joined value, without realising that this particular form only shown that option AFTER you have selected a field with a joined value... Doh! Now, i've hit the next problem because the second field I tried this with was one of those nasty Sharepoint multi-select choice columns and i can't work out how to copy the value properly. Looks like another question...

Answer (score 1):

Colin,

You can use [Update List Item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx) action in SharePoint Designer Workflow...

I am assuming that you have Request Item Id in Review List... See below screenshot!
[image]

I hope this helps